# jquery find input before button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single form on the page and I have some jQuery to make sure that the inputs have been completed before the submit.

But now I need to have multiple similar forms repeated on the page and I need to change the jQuery to only check the two inputs in the form that the button was clicked and not check any other form on the page.

```
<div class="offerDate">
    <form class="form-inline hidden-phone" action="http://www.treacyswestcounty.com/bookings/" method="get">
        <fieldset> 
            <input type="text" name="from_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" id="from_date" class="input-small hasDatepicker">
            <input type="text" name="to_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" id="to_date" class="input-small hasDatepicker">
            <button id="submitDates" class="btn btn-main" type="submit">CHECK NOW</button>
         </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="offerDate">
    <form class="form-inline hidden-phone" action="http://www.treacyswestcounty.com/bookings/" method="get">
        <fieldset> 
            <input type="text" name="from_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" id="from_date" class="input-small hasDatepicker">
            <input type="text" name="to_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" id="to_date" class="input-small hasDatepicker">
            <button id="submitDates" class="btn btn-main" type="submit">CHECK NOW</button>
         </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jQuery that I have used previously to check on form using ID

```
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    jQuery('#submitDates').click(function () {
    var found = false;
    jQuery("#to_date, #from_date").each(function(i,name){
        // Check if field is empty or not
        if (!found && jQuery(name).val()=='') {
        alert ('Please choose your arrival and departure dates!')
        found = true;
        } ;
    });
    return !found;
    });
```

Comment: ids should be unique. Do not have both buttons with `id="submitDates"`.

Comment: yes sorry that had been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this:

**CODE**

```
jQuery('.submitDates').click(function () {
 var found = false;
 jQuery(this).siblings("input").each(function (i, name) {
     // Check if field is empty or not
     if (!found && jQuery(name).val() == '') {
         alert('Please choose your arrival and departure dates!')
         found = true;
     };
 });
 return !found;
```

});

assuming your `inputs` are siblings for the `button`. Note I also changed button's `id` into `class`.

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/FY9P9/

Answer (score 3):

> .prev( [selector ] )
>
> Returns: jQuery
>
> Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

This is quite short and will target any input displayed just before a button :

```
$("button").prev("input")
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/R7zva/)

Comment: sorry I should clearer, could I put that into an object and then use that in the part of .each where I have jQuery("#to_date, #from_date").each

Answer (score 0):

Closest and Find do it as well, wherever the input are for the button :

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
    <input type="text" class="toDate" />
    <input type="text" class="fromDate" />
    <div class="button">Click</div>
</form>
<form class="form">
    <input type="text" class="toDate" />
    <input type="text" class="fromDate" />
    <div class="button">Click</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".button").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        if (($(this).closest(".form").find(".toDate").val() == "") || ($(this).closest(".form").find(".fromDate").val() == "")) {
            alert("Please fill in arrival and departure Date");
        }
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GuqJF/1/